# Django database model for my website

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am building an aviation website where I need to store aircraft manufacturer, type and version of a particular aircraft....Boeing 777 300 is an example. Here boeing is manufact., 777 version and 300 model. 
The model I use is:

```
     class Manufa(mod...):
     name=charfield
```

....

```
 manufact=models.ForeignKey(Manufact)
 type=models.ForeignKey(Type)
 version=models.ForeignKey(Version)
```

This allows for easy search but the problem is every time I have to display the item in search, i have to make three separate queries to get the full name of the aircraft form the foreign key id....For a search page with 100 items...thats unimaginable number of queries..

If I store these as names then if I change the version name or something then I will have to edit each of the rows...How do I solve this so that I can get the aircraft name from the same row...no second query..

Answer (score 0):

You just have to read more of the great django docs ;)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

btw. you should post your full model definition